# Bittorrent: Where do IP addresses come into picture?

Tags: protocols, bittorrent

I am reading about the Bittorrent protocol and couldn't find this mentioned on the Wiki page. I could understand the role of trackers and publishers but from a practical perspective, I tried contacting a tracker to give me some information and it gave me the following:

```
7%00%00%04%82%91%F3%CA%D5%92%08%C8%7C%B0%AE%1E4%2B%E4C:0:1
```

Now, the long string in the beginning is perhaps the info hash. As a next step, I did this:

```
http://tracker.sometracker.com/announce?info_hash=7%00%00%04%82%91%F3%CA%D5%92%08%C8%7C%B0%AE%1E4%2B%E4C
```

It gave me back a torrent file. So far so good. The torrent file contained this:

```
d8:completei0e10:downloadedi0e10:incompletei2e8:intervali1931e12:min intervali965e5:peers12:U���ٿ��ӣǣ^@^@e
```

I went to this site: `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file` but couldn't find any description (or perhaps missed it). Now, if I am the client and I get this file, where do I get the list of IP addresses that have the file?

Answer (score 0):

In the bencoded string that the tracker returns, the `peers` string is a list of peer addresses. Each address is 6 bytes -- 4 bytes for IPv4 address and 2 bytes for the port on which the peer is listening for connections.

`peers12:U���ٿ��ӣǣ^@^@e` contains the addresses (i.e. IPv4 and port) for 2 peers, since the `peers` value is 12 bytes long.

See [the bittorrent wiki spec](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Response) for more info.